# CDN socket.io.js referenced at wrong directory by polling-xhr.js when polling

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, npm, socket.io

I am attempting to get socket.io working again after a move to SSL. After setting up the SSL cert and changing all the codebase internal links with `http:` to `https:` the code started throwing an error:

```
Unable to get property 'emit' of undefined or null reference
```

I checked the console and found the reference to socket.io in the index.html file (`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`, the same thing listed in on the official socket.io website, was now producing a 404. I ran `npm remove socket.io`, which was at 0.9, and ran `npm install socket.io`, to install the current version, 2.0.3. Same error. I then tried copying the socket.io.js file into the project lib file, which I know to be publicly accessible.

After copying this to the known publicly accessible directory I received constantly updating console errors, each one being a slightly different version of the following:

```
polling-xhr.js:264 XHR finished loading: GET "https://www.cubicverse.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LpqO5Q2".
```

I then switched out the /lib local reference for this CDN:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Now I am getting the same polling errors interspersed very occasionally with this one:

```
polling-xhr.js:264 GET https://www.cubicverse.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LpqOPOQ 404 (Not Found)
i.create @ polling-xhr.js:264
i @ polling-xhr.js:165
o.request @ polling-xhr.js:92
o.doPoll @ polling-xhr.js:122
r.poll @ polling.js:118
r.doOpen @ polling.js:63
r.open @ transport.js:80
r.open @ socket.js:246
r @ socket.js:120
r @ socket.js:29
r.open.r.connect @ manager.js:226
(anonymous) @ manager.js:540
```

After the edits I made installing the SSL the server.js code now looks like this:

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function (suffix)
{
    return (this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) !== -1);
}

String.prototype.startsWith = function (prefix)
{
    return (this.substr(0, prefix.length) == prefix);
}

String.prototype.contains = function (toSearch)
{
    return (this.indexOf(toSearch) != -1);
}

Array.prototype.inArray = function (obj)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        if (this[i] == obj)
            return true;
    return false;
}

Array.prototype.append = function (arr)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        this[this.length] = arr[i];
}

String.prototype.leftPad = function (char, length)
{
    var result = this;
    while (result.length < length)
    {
        result = char + result;
    }

    return result;
}

String.prototype.hashPassword = function (salt)
{
    var crypto = require('crypto');
    return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(salt + this).digest('base64');
}

var nextPlayerId = 1;

var app = require('http').createServer(handler), 
    fs = require('fs'),
    privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('./server.key', 'utf8'),
    certificate = fs.readFileSync('./server.crt', 'utf8'),
    credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate},
    httpsapp = require('https').createServer(credentials, handler),
    url = require("url"),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app, { log: true }),
    path = require("path");
var zlib = require('zlib');
var config = require('./config');

GLOBAL.secureKey = config.secureKey;

io.enable('browser client minification');

io.sockets.on('connection', socketHandler);

var knownExt = [
    ['.html', 'text/html'],
    ['.js', 'text/javascript'],
    ['.css', 'text/css'],
    ['.png', 'image/png'],
    ['.jpg', 'image/jpeg'],
    ['.gif', 'image/gif'],
    ['.mp3', 'audio/mpeg'],
    ['.ogg', 'audio/ogg'],
    ['.dae', 'text/plain'],
    ['.txt', 'text/plain']
];

var moduleDirs = ['modules/', 'admin/', 'object_codes/', 'block_codes/', '3dgeometry/'];
var worldGenModuleDirs = ['special_areas/', 'world_details/'];

GLOBAL.getDb = function ()
{
    var mongodb = require("mongodb"),
        mongoserver = new mongodb.Server("localhost", 27017, {});
    return new mongodb.Db(config.dbName, mongoserver, {safe: true});
}

GLOBAL.after_login = new Array();
GLOBAL.after_disconnect = new Array();
GLOBAL.socketFunctions = new Array();
GLOBAL.socketFunctions[GLOBAL.socketFunctions.length] = {name: 'ping', action: function (socket, data)
{
    socket.pingDate = new Date();
}};
GLOBAL.socketFunctions[GLOBAL.socketFunctions.length] = {name: 'position', action: socketPositionUpdate};
GLOBAL.socketFunctions[GLOBAL.socketFunctions.length] = {name: 'disconnect', action: function (socket, data)
{
    var playerId = socket.playerId;
    //socket.broadcast.emit('player_disconnect', {playerId: socket.playerId});
    // Remove useless sockets
    for (var i = 0; i < GLOBAL.sockets.length; i++)
    {
        if (playerId == GLOBAL.sockets[i].playerId)
        {
            GLOBAL.sockets.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }

    /*for (var i = 0; i < GLOBAL.sockets.length; i++)
     GLOBAL.sockets[i].emit('player_disconnect', {playerId: playerId});*/
    socket.broadcast.emit('player_disconnect', {playerId: playerId});
    for (var i = 0; i < GLOBAL.after_disconnect.length; i++)
        GLOBAL.after_disconnect[i](socket);
}};

setInterval(checkTimeout, 1000);

GLOBAL.updatePositionFunctions = new Array();
GLOBAL.specialUri = new Array();

GLOBAL.sockets = new Array();

require('./user_storage.js');
require('./map_storage.js');
require('./general_data.js');
require('./wiki.js');
require('./chat.js');
require('./chat_bot.js');
require('./chat_bot_sentences.js');
require('./player_market.js');
require('./player_owned_areas.js');
require('./news.js');
require('./books.js');
require('./payment_done.js');

var baseDir = process.cwd();
if (baseDir.endsWith('server'))
{
    baseDir = path.resolve(baseDir, "..");
}

//console.log(baseDir);

function handler(request, response)
{
    var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

    if (uri == "/")
        uri = "/index.html"
    else if (uri == "/chat" || uri == "/chat/")
        uri = "/chat/index.html";

    for (var i = 0; i < GLOBAL.specialUri.length; i++)
    {
        if (uri.substr(0, GLOBAL.specialUri[i].name.length) == GLOBAL.specialUri[i].name)
        {
            GLOBAL.specialUri[i].action(request, response);
            return;
        }
    }

    var filename = path.join(baseDir, uri);

    if (uri == "/index.html")
    {
        mainFile(request, response);
        return;
    }
    if (uri == "/welcome.html")
    {
        welcomeFile(request, response);
        return;
    }
    else if (uri == "/allModulesCode.js")
    {
        modulesCode(request, response);
        return;
    }
    /*else if (uri == "/cv.appcache")
     {
     manifestFile(request, response);
     return;
     }*/

    fs.exists(filename, function (exists)
        {
            var isOk = true;
            try
            {
                if (!exists)
                    isOk = false;
                else if (fs.statSync(filename).isDirectory())
                    isOk = false;
            }
            catch (err)
            {
                isOk = false;
            }

            if (uri.startsWith("/server/"))
                isOk = false;
            if (uri.contains("..") || uri.contains("./") || uri.contains("/."))
                isOk = false;

            if (!isOk)
            {
                response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
                response.write("404 Not Found\n");
                response.end();
                return;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < knownExt.length; i++)
            {
                if (filename.endsWith(knownExt[i][0]))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (filename.endsWith('.js') || filename.endsWith('.html'))
                        {
                            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": knownExt[i][1], "Expires": -1, "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate", "Pragma": "no-cache"});
                            fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(response);
                        }
                        else if (filename.endsWith('.css'))
                        {
                            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": knownExt[i][1], "Expires": -1, "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate", "Pragma": "no-cache"});
                            cssCode(filename, response);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": knownExt[i][1], "Cache-Control": "max-age=31536000", "Cache-Control": "public", "Expires": new Date(((new Date()).getTime() + 1000 * 31536000))});
                            fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(response);
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                        (ex)
                    {
                        console.log(ex)
                        response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
                        response.write("404 Not Found\n");
                        response.end();
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }

            response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            response.write("404 Not Found\n");
            response.end();
        }
    );
}

function modulesCode(request, response)
{
    response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/javascript", "Expires": -1, "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate", "Pragma": "no-cache" });

    response.write("var codeLines=[];");
    var nbLines = 1;

    var allDirs = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < moduleDirs.length; j++)
        allDirs[allDirs.length] = moduleDirs[j];
    for (var j = 0; j < worldGenModuleDirs.length; j++)
        allDirs[allDirs.length] = worldGenModuleDirs[j];

    for (var j = 0; j < allDirs.length; j++)
    {
        var files = fs.readdirSync(baseDir + '/' + allDirs[j]);
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            if (files[i].endsWith(".js"))
            {
                response.write("\n// ----------------------------\n");
                response.write("// " + allDirs[j] + "/" + files[i] + "\n");
                nbLines += 4;
                var data = fs.readFileSync(baseDir + '/' + allDirs[j] + "/" + files[i], "utf8");
                var dataLines = data.split('\n').length;
                response.write("codeLines[codeLines.length]={fromLine:" + nbLines + ",toLine:" + (nbLines + dataLines) + ",name:'" + allDirs[j] + "/" + files[i] + "'}\n");
                nbLines += dataLines;
                response.write("// ----------------------------\n");

                response.write(data);
            }
        }
    }

    response.write("\n\n// ----------------------------\n");
    response.write("// images dates\n");
    response.write("// ----------------------------\n");
    response.write("var imageVersion={};\n");
    var contentDirs = ['/images', '/3dmodels'];
    for (var j = 0; j < contentDirs.length; j++)
    {
        var files = fs.readdirSync(baseDir + contentDirs[j]);
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            var s = fs.statSync(baseDir + contentDirs[j] + '/' + files[i]);
            response.write("imageVersion['" + files[i] + "']='" + s.mtime.getTime() + "';\n");
        }
    }

    response.write("\n// ----------------------------\n");
    response.write("// Init\n");
    response.write("initialize();");

    /*var code = "";
     code += "var codeLines=[];";
     var nbLines = 1;

     var allDirs = [];
     for (var j = 0; j < moduleDirs.length; j++)
     allDirs[allDirs.length] = moduleDirs[j];
     for (var j = 0; j < worldGenModuleDirs.length; j++)
     allDirs[allDirs.length] = worldGenModuleDirs[j];

     //var path = require('path');

     var mustUpdated = true;
     if (fs.existsSync(baseDir + '/cache/allModulesCode.js'))
     {
     mustUpdated = false;
     var cacheFile = fs.statSync(baseDir + '/cache/allModulesCode.js').mtime.getTime();

     for (var j = 0; j < allDirs.length && mustUpdated == false; j++)
     {
     var files = fs.readdirSync(baseDir + '/' + allDirs[j]);
     for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
     {
     if (files[i].endsWith(".js"))
     {
     if (fs.statSync(baseDir + '/' + allDirs[j] + "/" + files[i]).mtime.getTime() >= cacheFile)
     {
     mustUpdated = true;
     break;
     }
     }
     }
     }
     }

     if (!mustUpdated)
     {
     //response.write(fs.readFileSync(baseDir + '/cache/allModulesCode.js', "utf8"));
     response.write(fs.readFileSync(baseDir + '/cache/allModulesCode.js.orig', "utf8"));
     response.end();
     return;
     }

     for (var j = 0; j < allDirs.length; j++)
     {
     var files = fs.readdirSync(baseDir + '/' + allDirs[j]);
     for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
     {
     if (files[i].endsWith(".js"))
     {
     code += "\n// ----------------------------\n";
     code += "// " + allDirs[j] + "/" + files[i] + "\n";
     nbLines += 4;
     var data = fs.readFileSync(baseDir + '/' + allDirs[j] + "/" + files[i], "utf8");
     var dataLines = data.split('\n').length;
     code += "codeLines[codeLines.length]={fromLine:" + nbLines + ",toLine:" + (nbLines + dataLines) + ",name:'" + allDirs[j] + "/" + files[i] + "'}\n";
     nbLines += dataLines;
     code += "// ----------------------------\n";

     code += data;
     }
     }
     }

     code += "\n\n// ----------------------------\n";
     code += "// images dates\n";
     code += "// ----------------------------\n";
     code += "var imageVersion={};\n";
     var files = fs.readdirSync(baseDir + '/images');
     for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
     {
     var s = fs.statSync(baseDir + '/images/' + files[i]);
     code += "imageVersion['" + files[i] + "']='" + s.mtime.getTime() + "';\n";
     }

     code += "\n// ----------------------------\n";
     code += "// Init\n";
     code += "initialize();";

     var UglifyJS = require("uglify-js");
     fs.writeFile(baseDir + '/cache/allModulesCode.js.orig', code+"\n\ncodeStyle='orig'\n", "utf8");
     var result = UglifyJS.minify(code+"\n\ncodeStyle='mini'\n", {fromString: true});
     var miniCode = result.code;
     fs.writeFile(baseDir + '/cache/allModulesCode.js', miniCode, "utf8");
     response.write(code+"\n\ncodeStyle='orig'\n");
     //response.write(miniCode);*/

    response.end();
}

function cssCode(filename, response)
{
    //fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(response);
    //console.log(filename)
    fs.readFile(filename, "utf8", function (err, fileData)
    {
        fileData = fileData;
        var files = fs.readdirSync(baseDir + '/images');
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            var r = new RegExp(files[i].replace(".", "\\."), "g");
            var s = fs.statSync(baseDir + '/images/' + files[i]);
            fileData = fileData.replace(r, files[i] + "?v=" + s.mtime.getTime());
        }
        //console.log(fileData)
        response.write(fileData);
        response.end();
    });
}

function mainFile(request, response)
{
    var filename = path.join(baseDir, "/index.html");
    //console.log(filename);

    fs.readFile(filename, function (err, fileData)
    {
        response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html", "Expires": -1, "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate", "Pragma": "no-cache" });

        var worldGenModules = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < worldGenModuleDirs.length; j++)
        {
            var files = fs.readdirSync(baseDir + '/' + worldGenModuleDirs[j]);
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
            {
                if (files[i].endsWith(".js"))
                {
                    worldGenModules[worldGenModules.length] = worldGenModuleDirs[j] + files[i];
                    //modules[modules.length] = worldGenModuleDirs[j] + files[i];
                }
            }
        }

        //response.write(("" + fileData).replace("#title#", config.title).replace("'#modules#'", JSON.stringify(modules)).replace("'#worldGenModules#'", JSON.stringify(worldGenModules)));
        response.write(("" + fileData).replace("#title#", config.title).replace("'#worldGenModules#'", JSON.stringify(worldGenModules)));
        response.end();
    });
}

function sortByDate(a, b)
{
    if (a.date < b.date)
        return 1;
    if (b.date < a.date)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}

/*function manifestFile(request, response)
 {
 response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/cache-manifest", "Expires": -1, "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate", "Pragma": "no-cache" });

 var dirs = [];
 dirs.append(moduleDirs);
 dirs.append(worldGenModuleDirs);
 dirs.append(["images/"]);

 var maxfs = 0;

 for (var j = 0; j < dirs.length; j++)
 {
 //console.log(baseDir + "/" + dirs[j])
 var files = fs.readdirSync(baseDir + "/" + dirs[j]);
 for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
 {
 var s = fs.statSync(baseDir + '/' + dirs[j] + files[i]);
 var s = s.mtime.getTime();
 if (s > maxfs)
 maxfs = s;
 }
 }

 response.write("CACHE MANIFEST\n");
 response.write("# Version " + s + "\n");

 for (var j = 0; j < dirs.length; j++)
 {
 //console.log(baseDir + "/" + dirs[j])
 var files = fs.readdirSync(baseDir + "/" + dirs[j]);
 for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
 {
 var s = fs.statSync(baseDir + '/' + dirs[j] + files[i]);
 var s = s.mtime.getTime();
 if (s > maxfs)
 maxfs = s;
 }
 }

 response.write("/index.html\n");
 response.write("/socket.io/socket.io.js\n");
 response.write("/lib/random.js\n");
 response.write("/lib/perlin.js\n");
 response.write("/main.js\n");
 response.write("/allModulesCode.js\n");

 for (var j = 0; j < dirs.length; j++)
 {
 //console.log(baseDir + "/" + dirs[j])
 var files = fs.readdirSync(baseDir + "/" + dirs[j]);
 for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
 {
 if (files[i].endsWith(".css"))
 response.write('/' + dirs[j] + files[i] + '\n');
 }
 }

 var files = fs.readdirSync(baseDir + "/images");
 for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
 {
 var s = fs.statSync(baseDir + '/images/' + files[i]);
 var s = s.mtime.getTime();
 response.write('/images/' + files[i] + '?v=' + s + '\n');
 }

 response.end();
 }*/

function welcomeFile(request, response)
{
    var filename = path.join(baseDir, "/welcome.html");
    //console.log(filename);

    fs.readFile(filename, function (err, fileData)
    {
        response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html", "Expires": -1, "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate", "Pragma": "no-cache" });

        var db = GLOBAL.getDb();

        db.open(function (err, db)
        {
            if (db == null)
            {
                fileData = ("" + fileData).replace("#news#", "");
                response.write(fileData.replace("#top#", ""));
                return;
            }

            db.collection("news", function (err, collection)
            {
                collection.find().toArray(function (err, data)
                {
                    var news = "<ul>";
                    data.sort(sortByDate);
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length && i < 5; i++)
                        news += "<li><b>" + data[i].date + ":</b> " + data[i].text + "</li>";
                    news += "</ul>";
                    fileData = ("" + fileData).replace("#news#", news);

                    db.collection("top", function (err, collection)
                    {
                        if (collection == null)
                        {
                            response.write(fileData.replace("#top#", ""));
                            response.end();
                            db.close();
                            return;
                        }
                        collection.findOne({_id: "user"}, function (err, data)
                        {
                            if (data == null)
                            {
                                response.write(fileData.replace("#top#", ""));
                                response.end();
                                db.close();
                                return;
                            }
                            var top = "<table>";
                            top += "<tr><td>Best players:</td><td>Level:</td></tr>";
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.level.length && i < 15; i++)
                            {
                                top += "<tr><td>" + data.level[i].username + "</td><td>" + data.level[i].value + "</td></tr>";
                            }
                            top += "</table>";
                            response.write(fileData.replace("#top#", top));
                            response.end();
                            db.close();
                            return;
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
}

function socketHandler(socket)
{
    GLOBAL.sockets[GLOBAL.sockets.length] = socket;
    socket.playerId = nextPlayerId++;
    socket.pingDate = new Date();
    socket.broadcast.emit('player_connect', {playerId: socket.playerId});
    socket.emit('player_id', {playerId: socket.playerId});

    for (var i = 0; i < GLOBAL.socketFunctions.length; i++)
        eval("socket.on(GLOBAL.socketFunctions[" + i + "].name,function (data) { GLOBAL.socketFunctions[" + i + "].action(socket,data); });");
}

function socketPositionUpdate(socket, data)
{
    //console.log("ID: "+data.playerId+", X: "+data.x+", Y: "+data.y+" Z: "+data.z);
    // Send players within the areas
    for (var i = 0; i < GLOBAL.sockets.length; i++)
    {
        if (GLOBAL.sockets[i].playerId == socket.playerId)
            continue;
        if (GLOBAL.sockets[i].position == undefined && Math.abs(data.ax) < 2 && Math.abs(data.ay) < 2)
        {
            GLOBAL.sockets[i].emit('player_position', data);
            continue;
        }
        if (GLOBAL.sockets[i].position == undefined || GLOBAL.sockets[i].position.ax == null)
            continue;
        if (Math.abs(GLOBAL.sockets[i].position.ax - data.ax) > 1 || Math.abs(GLOBAL.sockets[i].position.ay - data.ay) > 1)
            continue;
        GLOBAL.sockets[i].emit('player_position', data);
    }
    socket.position = data;
    for (var i = 0; i < GLOBAL.updatePositionFunctions.length; i++)
        GLOBAL.updatePositionFunctions[i](socket, data);
}

function checkTimeout()
{
    /*var now = new Date();
     for (var i = 0; i < GLOBAL.sockets.length; i++)
     {
     var diff = (now - GLOBAL.sockets[i].pingDate) / 1000;
     if (diff > 60 && GLOBAL.sockets[i].username != null && GLOBAL.sockets[i].username != undefined)
     {
     GLOBAL.sockets[i].emit('close_duplicate', {});
     GLOBAL.sockets[i].disconnect('unauthorized');
     }
     }*/
}

app.listen(config.port);
httpsapp.listen(config.httpsport);
```

How do I find out what's causing this error as it seems to be that a sub-library of socket.io is calling the wrong url, but obviously I don't want to be editing this directly (or at least, I would assume not)? Perhaps there might be something else in the codebase that's causing this URL to be called, via the `polling.xhr` library? If so, could someone suggest maybe a grep command or something like that which might allow me to isolate it? There's nothing obvious in any of the main server files, and with over 70,000 lines of code going through by hand isn't really an option. Anything else that's likely to fix this error?

Comment: Hi did you find the answer? I'm stuck in the same error!

Comment: @Adry never did... but I'm messing about with JavaScript websockets again, as it happens, so if I manage to reproduce the same error again, I'll make sure to let you know!